# Optimizing a large group of IF statements

Tags: php, if-statement, nested-if

I have a large group of nested IF statements and I was wondering If anyone had any suggestions on how to optimize for speed, size, and readability.

Below is a sample of ONE of the if statements and its' nested statements. There will be approximately 25-30 of these in the document.

```
if( $row["inlet_moisture"] > $row["inlet_moisture_high_warning"] ) {
    if( $row["inlet_moisture"] > $row["inlet_moisture_high_critical"] ) {
        if( $row["inlet_high_critical"] == 0 ) {
            if( $row["email_notification"] == 1 ) {

            }
            if( $row["mobile_notification"] == 1 ) {

            }
        }
    } else {
        if( $row["inlet_high_warning"] == 0 ) {
            if( $row["email_notification"] == 1 ) {

            }
            if( $row["mobile_notification"] == 1 ) {

            }
        }
    }
} else if( $row["inlet_moisture"] < $row["inlet_moisture_low_warning"] ) {
    if( $row["inlet_moisture"] < $row["inlet_moisture_low_critical"] ) {
        if( $row["inlet_low_critical"] == 0 ) {
            if( $row["email_notification"] == 1 ) {

            }
            if( $row["mobile_notification"] == 1 ) {

            }
        }
    } else {
        if( $row["inlet_low_warning"] == 0 ) {
            if( $row["email_notification"] == 1 ) {

            }
            if( $row["mobile_notification"] == 1 ) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is; I have a *reading* (temp/speed/moisture) and I need to check if it hits any of the limits (high warning / high critical / low warning / low critical), if it does I first need to check if I have already sent an alarm for that. If no alarm has been sent I then need to check if the user has requested alarm notification (mobile/email/both)

Currently this works. I Just don't like how heavy it is? Can I improve on this?

Thanks.

Comment: The first thing I would do to improve readability is create shorter variable names, e.g. `$inlet_moisture = $row["inlet_moisture"]`, and so on.  In the process, I would also convert to `boolean`, to avoid having to explicitly check `== 1` everywhere.

Comment: @Oli, will this have ramifications on performance? Also, The values are stored on my DB as boolean, however MySQL returns 0 and 1 for boolean values. Should I `$email_notification = $row["email_notification"] == 1 ? true : false;`

Comment: I suspect this will have approximately zero impact on performance (although you should profile it to confirm).  Also, you don't need the `? true : false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems to me much more clear, even though you could combine the nested ifs I'd rather prefer this one

```
if( $row["inlet_moisture"] > $row["inlet_moisture_high_critical"] ) {
  if( $row["inlet_high_critical"] == 0 ) {
   $message = 'the pertinent message';
  }
}
else if( $row["inlet_moisture"] > $row["inlet_moisture_high_warning"] ) {
  if( $row["inlet_high_warning"] == 0 ) {
   $message = 'the pertinent message';
  }
}
else if( $row["inlet_moisture"] < $row["inlet_moisture_low_critical"] ) {
  if( $row["inlet_low_critical"] == 0 ) {
   $message = 'the pertinent message';
  }
}
else if( $row["inlet_moisture"] < $row["inlet_moisture_low_warning"] ) {
  if( $row["inlet_low_warning"] == 0 ) {
   $message = 'the pertinent message';
  }
}


if( $row["email_notification"] == 1 ) {
  sendMessage($message, $email);
}
if( $row["mobile_notification"] == 1 ) {
  sendMessage($message, $mobile);    
}
```

Comment: you could initializa $message as false or null at the beginning, in order to use it as a flag later at the notification conditions. for example: if ($row["email_notification"] && $message) {...}

Answer (score 2):

[Premature optimisation is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) - with what we are dealing with here, no matter what you do it won't have much/any noticable impact on performance.

Having said that, a large amount of `if` statements can often be replaced with one or more `switch` structures, although whether this improves performance *or* readability is debatable. You may also be able to create some functions for repeated bits of code, although this may actually negatively impact performance.

From your comment above... creating variables with nicer names will have pretty much zero impact on performance. If will slightly increase your memory usage, but the processing time impact will be next to zero. And, if you are evaluating the values as booleans, you don't need to convert them to booleans explicitly, because 1 still evaluates to `TRUE`, and 0 to `FALSE`. However, if you do want to do it

```
$email_notification = $row["email_notification"] == 1 ? true : false;
```

...is unnecessarily long winded, you can do either this:

```
$email_notification = $row["email_notification"] == 1;
```

...or...

```
$email_notification = (bool) $row["email_notification"];
```

...and it will have the same effect.

Comment: My biggest 'optimization' point would be is it possible; with the above requirements / structure, to make this any smaller or compact but still handle all cases. but I like your points.

Comment: @rlemon From the code above, if what you are bothered about is the size of the document, you could reduce that to a single block and a `foreach`, but this would likely reduce performance. I'll edit my answer to show you what I mean...

Comment: @rlemon Scratch that Feida Kila's response is probably what you are after. Not really any more processor/memory efficient but will definitely improve readability.